# PHP: Serial Number Authentication

Tags: php

I am not very experienced in php and I am trying to learn some basics. Here I have an array which contains serial numbers. I would like it when the input matches a serial number, the serialnumber is removed from the array.

I believe this code accomplishes it. But my issue is setting it up.

I want it when someone visits my site.

http://example.com/serialnumbervalidate.php?key=somekey

that somekey is sent as data to the php script then validated. How can this be accomplished?

```
<?php

    $serialnumbers= array('2r3ewfasd', '21rfsasad', '34t3rfdsas');
    foreach ($serialnumbers as $number) {
        if(($key = array_search($number, $serialnumbers )) !== false) {
            unset($messages[$number]);
            die("found"); 
        } else {  
            die("not found.");
        }  
    }           
?>
```

Comment: If you want it to transmit trough the URL, use `$_GET` - if you want it to be transmitted in the background, without being in the url (the normal case for user inputs) - use `$_POST`

Comment: you can get key there: `$key = $_GET['key'];`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove the `key` as denoted in the querystring you could do the following

```
$userkey=$_GET['key'];


$serialnumbers= array('2r3ewfasd', '21rfsasad', '34t3rfdsas');
if( in_array( $userkey, $serialnumbers ) ){
    array_splice( $serialnumbers, array_search( $userkey, $serialnumbers ), 1 );
}
```

I'm not sure why you think the found value is not being removed from the array. Consider the following test

```
/* utility function */
function pre($data){
    echo '<pre>',print_r($data,true),'</pre>';
}


$serialnumbers= array('2r3ewfasd', '21rfsasad', '34t3rfdsas');

/* Show original data in array */
pre($serialnumbers);

/* set a variable with user supplied `key` parameter */
$userkey=$_GET['key'];

/* search for and remove `$key` from original array */
if( in_array( $userkey, $serialnumbers ) ){
    array_splice( $serialnumbers, array_search( $userkey, $serialnumbers ), 1 );
}   

/* Show array after operation */
pre($serialnumbers);

/* pseudo test url used */
#https://localhost/test/?key=34t3rfdsas

/* output */
Array
(
    [0] => 2r3ewfasd
    [1] => 21rfsasad
    [2] => 34t3rfdsas
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2r3ewfasd
    [1] => 21rfsasad
)
```

Comment: I really like this option. The issue people users can still use the same serialnumber again and again.

Comment: `"The issue people users can still use the same serialnumber again and again."` ? Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: The value found does not remove itself from the array.

Comment: Thanks for the great example. Understood

Comment: If you are looking for a mechanism that will remove the user supplied key permanently and make it unavailable for another user at another time then you would need to use a different technology. The above code could be run by two people at the same time using the same key and they would get the same result as it is temporal in nature. Consider a database for storage of serialnumbers and their permanent removal

Comment: @JohanDoe Just as RamRaider said in the above comment. You might also consider adding an additional condition to it, i.e.: `&userID=$unique_user` type of thing and possibly using an encoding/decoding method.

Answer (score 1):

The `array_search` function already loop through your array, so don't do it yourself, as for your question, `$_GET[<name of your variable>]` shoud be used :

```
<?php
$number = $_GET['key'];
$serialnumbers= array('2r3ewfasd', '21rfsasad', '34t3rfdsas');
if(($key = array_search($number, $serialnumbers )) !== false) {
    unset($messages[$number]);
    die("found"); 
}else{  
    die("not found.");
}
?>
```

Comment: Ah sorry. My mistake.

Comment: @JohanDoe As for what I had read in other comments. `GET` / `POST` is absolutely not to hide variable from request, it is just different methods of the HTTP protocol to transmit data. I strongly suggest you to read introduction about the HTTP protocol which will be very handy to know if you plan to develop web based applications

Comment: @Esteben I understand. I am just some .NET and C++ programmer who has never touched up on web developement and would like to learn how to provide authentication for my programs and know how its done.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than explain why your code isn't working, consider:

```
$serialnumbers= array('2r3ewfasd', '21rfsasad', '34t3rfdsas');
foreach ($serialnumbers as $index=>$number) {
    if($_GET['key'] === $number) {
        unset($messages[$index]);
        die("found"); 
    } else {  
        die("not found.");
    }  
}
```

But it would be less effort (and when you have more than 3 items in the array, a lot faster) to do this:

```
$serialnumbers= array(
 '2r3ewfasd'=>1, 
 '21rfsasad'=>1, 
 '34t3rfdsas'=>1);
if ($serialnumbers[$_GET['key']]) {
  $serialnumbers[$_GET['key']]=0;
  die ('found');
}
die ('not found');
```